# Resize an image in xml automatically - Android

Tags: java, android

I have the following in my xml -

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/isPlaying"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/greenlight"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

The image is of a green traffic light but within design view, if I resize the image, it crops it out. So the green traffic light outline crops out and all you see is a green squre. How do I set it that if I resize the image it shrinks the image instead of cropping it out?

Thanks

Comment: set scaleType "fitXY" instance of "center"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Add property : `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`**

Example :

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"     
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
  android:maxWidth="42dp"  
  android:maxHeight="42dp"  
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
  android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"  
  android:src="@drawable/greenlight" 
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ScaleType to your XML. I believe CENTER_INSIDE will work for you, since the rest of the image is being cropped out.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/isPlaying"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:scaleType="center_inside"
        android:src="@drawable/greenlight"
        android:visibility="visible"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for, I cannot upvote your answer at the moment but just wanted you to know it helped!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

for adjusting your image you can use scaleType="fitXY"